Binomial distribution vs conventional probability
Find the probability of getting 5 exactly twice in 7 throws of a die: Binomial distribution -> 7C2 x (1/6)^2 (5/6)^5 conventional probability method - 7C2/6^7
question -> If 7C2 gives us the total ways of selecting exactly two 5's then by common sense, we divide it by total sample space i.e 6^7 it should give us the proper result(because 7C2 is the subset of total space anyway), but binomial distribution which of course seems right too give us a different result why?
(after our general explanation, please tell me how can both things differ in real scenarios)

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The sample space of elementary outcomes of $7$ rolls of a fair six-sided die has $6^7$ elements:  e.g.,
$$(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_7) = (1,5,3,2,2,4,1)$$
is one such element.  In each position $x_i$ of the $7$-tuple, the value of $x_i$ represents the outcome of the $i^{\rm th}$ die roll; there are $7$ positions and $6$ outcomes for each roll.  Each elementary outcome is equiprobable.
However, if you want to count the number of such outcomes with exactly two $5$s, then you must do two things:  count the positions in which the $5$s appear, and count the number of ways to choose the outcomes of the remaining non-$5$ die rolls.  For instance, in the outcome
$$(4,5,6,5,2,1,2),$$
there are exactly two $5$s--one on the second roll, and one on the fourth.  But here is another distinct outcome with two $5$s in the same position, but with values in the other rolls that may or may not be the same:
$$(3,5,1,5,6,4,2).$$
This one must also be counted because both are elements of the sample space of elementary outcomes you have chosen to construct.
So, there are $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ ways to choose the two positions of the $5$s; that much is clear.  For each of these $21$ ways, there are $5^5$ choices for the remaining non-$5$ die rolls:  the base $5 = 7-2$ represents the number of positions remaining that do not have a $5$ roll; and the exponent $5 = 6-1$ represents the number of outcomes of a single die roll from which we may choose as values.  So in total, there are
$$\binom{7}{2} 5^5$$
such outcomes, out of $6^7$ elementary outcomes, for a probability of
$$\binom{7}{2} \frac{5^5}{6^7} = \frac{21875}{93312}.$$
This is identical to the binomial probability:
$$\binom{7}{2} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2 \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5 = \frac{21875}{93312}.$$
